# Construct infinite sorted list without adding duplicates

Tags: algorithm, list, haskell, duplicates, generator

I am relatively new to Haskell, but I am trying to learn both by reading and trying to solve problems on Project Euler. I am currently trying to implement a function that takes an infinite list of integers and returns the ordered list of pairwise sums of elements in said list. I am really looking for solutions to the specific issue I am facing, rather than advice on different strategies or approaches, but those are welcome as well, as being a coder doesn't mean knowing how to implement a strategy, but also choosing the best strategy  available.

My approach relies on traversing an infinite list of infinite generators and retrieving elements in order, with several mathematical properties that are useful in implementing my solution.

If I were trying to obtain the sequence of pairwise sums of the natural numbers, for example, this would be my code:

```
myList :: [Integer]
myList = [1..]

myGens :: [[Integer]]
myGens = gens myList
    where
        gens = \xs -> map (\x -> [x+y|y<-(dropWhile (<x) xs)]) xs
```

Regardless of the number set used, provided that it is sorted, the following conditions hold:

- ∀ i ≥ 0, `head (gens xs !! i) == 2*(myList !! i)`
- ∀ i,j,k ≥ 0, l > 0, `(((gens xs) !! i) !! j) < (((gens xs) !! i+k) !! j+l)`

Special cases for the second condition are:

- ∀ i,j ≥ 0, `(((gens xs) !! i) !! j) < (((gens xs) !! i+1) !! j)`
- ∀ i,j ≥ 0, k > 0, `(((gens xs) !! i) !! j) < (((gens xs) !! i+k) !! j)`

Here is the particular code I am trying to modify:

```
stride :: [Integer] -> [Int] -> [[Integer]] -> [Integer]
stride xs cs xss = x : stride xs counts streams
        where
            (x,i) = step xs cs xss
            counts = inc i cs
            streams = chop i xss

step :: [Integer] -> [Int] -> [[Integer]] -> (Integer,Int)
step xs cs xss = pace xs (defer cs xss)

pace :: [Integer] -> [(Integer,Int)] -> (Integer,Int)
pace hs xs@((x,i):xt) = minim (x,i) hs xt
    where
        minim :: (Integer,Int) -> [Integer] -> [(Integer,Int)] -> (Integer,Int)
        minim m _ [] = m
        minim m@(g,i) hs (y@(h,n):ynt) | g > h && 2*(hs !! n) > h = y
                                       | g > h = minim y hs ynt
                                       | 2*(hs !! n) > g = m
                                       | otherwise = minim m hs ynt


defer :: [Int] -> [[a]] -> [(a,Int)]
defer cs xss = (infer (zip cs (zip (map head xss) [0..])))

infer :: [(Int,(a,Int))] -> [(a,Int)]
infer [] = []
infer ((c,xi):xis) | c == 0 = xi:[]
                   | otherwise = xi:(infer (dropWhile (\(p,(q,r)) -> p>=c) xis))
```

The set in question I am using has the property that multiple distinct pairs produce an identical sum. I want an efficient method of handling all duplicate elements at once, in order to avoid an increased cost of computing all the pairwise sums up to N, as it requires M more tests if M is the number of duplicates.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

### EDIT:

I made some changes to the code, independently of what was suggested, and would appreciate feedback on the relative efficiencies of my original code, my revised code, and the proposals so far.

```
stride :: [Integer] -> [Int] -> [[Integer]] -> [Integer]
stride xs cs xss = x : stride xs counts streams
where
    (x,is) = step xs cs xss
    counts = foldr (\i -> inc i) cs is
    streams = foldr (\i -> chop i) xss is

step :: [Integer] -> [Int] -> [[Integer]] -> (Integer,[Int])
step xs cs xss = pace xs (defer cs xss)

pace :: [Integer] -> [(Integer,Int)] -> (Integer,[Int])
pace hs xs@((x,i):xt) = minim (x,(i:[])) hs xt
    where
    minim :: (Integer,[Int]) -> [Integer] -> [(Integer,Int)] -> (Integer,[Int])
    minim m _ [] = m
    minim m@(g,is@(i:_)) hs (y@(h,n):ynt) | g > h && 2*(hs !! n) > h = (h,[n])
                              | g > h = minim (h,[n]) hs ynt
                              | g == h && 2*(hs !! n) > h = (g,n:is)
                          | g == h = minim (g,n:is) hs ynt
                          | g < h && 2*(hs !! n) > g = m
                          | g < h = minim m hs ynt
```

Also, I left out the code for `inc` and `chop`:

```
alter :: (a->a) -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
alter = \f -> \n -> \xs -> (take (n) xs) ++ [f (xs !! n)] ++ (drop (n+1) xs)

inc :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
inc = alter (1+)

chop :: Int -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
chop = alter (tail)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to present a solution that uses an infinite [pairing heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_heap). We'll have logarithmic overhead per element constructed, but [no one knows how to do better](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/TOPP/P41.html) (in a model with comparison-based methods and real numbers).

The first bit of code is just the standard pairing heap.

```
module Queue where
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

data Queue k = E
             | T k [Queue k]
             deriving Show

fromOrderedList :: (Ord k) => [k] -> Queue k
fromOrderedList [] = E
fromOrderedList [k] = T k []
fromOrderedList (k1 : ks'@(k2 : _ks''))
  | k1 <= k2 = T k1 [fromOrderedList ks']

mergePairs :: (Ord k) => [Queue k] -> Queue k
mergePairs [] = E
mergePairs [q] = q
mergePairs (q1 : q2 : qs'') = merge (merge q1 q2) (mergePairs qs'')

merge :: (Ord k) => Queue k -> Queue k -> Queue k
merge (E) q2 = q2
merge q1 (E) = q1
merge q1@(T k1 q1's) q2@(T k2 q2's)
  = if k1 <= k2 then T k1 (q2 : q1's) else T k2 (q1 : q2's)

deleteMin :: (Ord k) => Queue k -> Maybe (k, Queue k)
deleteMin (E) = Nothing
deleteMin (T k q's) = Just (k, mergePairs q's)

toOrderedList :: (Ord k) => Queue k -> [k]
toOrderedList q
  = fromMaybe [] $
      do (k, q') <- deleteMin q
         return (k : toOrderedList q')
```

Note that `fromOrderedList` accepts infinite lists. I think that this can be justified theoretically by pretending as though the infinite list of descendants effectively are merged "just in time". This feels like the kind of thing that should be in the literature on purely functional data structures already, but I'm going to be lazy and not look right now.

The function `mergeOrderedByMin` takes this one step further and merges a potentially infinite list of queues, where the min element in each queue is nondecreasing. I don't think that we can reuse `merge`, since `merge` appears to be insufficiently lazy.

```
mergeOrderedByMin :: (Ord k) => [Queue k] -> Queue k
mergeOrderedByMin [] = E
mergeOrderedByMin (E : qs') = mergeOrderedByMin qs'
mergeOrderedByMin (T k q's : qs')
  = T k (mergeOrderedByMin qs' : q's)
```

The next function removes duplicates from a sorted list. It's in the library that m09 suggested, but for the sake of completeness, I'll define it here.

```
nubOrderedList :: (Ord k) => [k] -> [k]
nubOrderedList [] = []
nubOrderedList [k] = [k]
nubOrderedList (k1 : ks'@(k2 : _ks''))
  | k1 < k2 = k1 : nubOrderedList ks'
  | k1 == k2 = nubOrderedList ks'
```

Finally, we put it all together. I'll use the squares as an example.

```
squares :: [Integer]
squares = map (^ 2) [0 ..]

sumsOfTwoSquares :: [Integer]
sumsOfTwoSquares
  = nubOrderedList $ toOrderedList $
      mergeOrderedByMin
        [fromOrderedList (map (s +) squares) | s <- squares]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to modify your code that much, you can use the [nub](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.6.1/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html#v%3anub) function of Data.List.Ordered (installable by `cabal install data-ordlist`) to filter duplicates out.

It runs in linear time, ie complexity wise your algorithm won't change.

Answer (score 2):

for your example `[1..]` the result is just `[2..]`. A "very smart compiler"  [could deduce this](https://www.google.com/search?q=supercompilation) from the general solution with implicit heap, that follows.

`gens xs` is better expressed as

```
gens xs = map (\t@(x:_) -> map (x+) t) $ tails xs   -- or should it be
     --   map (\(x:ys) -> map (x+) ys) $ tails xs   --                ?
```

Its resulting list of lists is easily merged without duplicates by [tree-like folding<sup>1</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29#Tree-like_folds) ([pictured here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Tree_merging)), with

```
pairsums xs = foldi (\(x:l) r-> x : union l r) $ gens xs
```

This assumes the input list is ordered in increasing order. If it's merely in non-decreasing order (with only finite *runs* of equals in it, of course), you'll need to slap an `orderedNub` on top of that ([as m09 mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23346284/849891)),

```
pairsums' = orderedNub . pairsums
```

Just by using `foldi` where `foldr` would work, we often get an algorithmic improvement in complexity from a factor of *n* to *log n*, a pretty significant speedup. I use it as a general tool all the time.

<sup>1</sup>The code, adjusted for infinite lists only:

```
foldi f (x:xs)  = f x (foldi f (pairs f xs))
pairs f (x:y:t) = f x y : pairs f t
union (x:xs) (y:ys) = case compare x y of           
                          LT -> x : union  xs (y:ys) 
                          EQ -> x : union  xs    ys  
                          GT -> y : union (x:xs) ys
```

See also:

- [mergesort as `foldtree`](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.general/15007/focus=15010) (by [Heinrich Apfelmus](http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/))
- [infinite tree folding (by Dave Bayer)](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.cafe/26426/focus=26493)
- [Implicit Heap (by apfelmus)](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers_miscellaneous#Implicit_Heap)

Comment: strange that even the topic starter didn't upvote this answer.

Comment: @SassaNF I guess the lone upvote is from you then? :) :) I'm not surprised, the newcomers on SO too often are not keeping engaged with their questions. In this case, the OP was last online on `May 14`, so they haven't even seen this answer. I've had some answers accepted/upvoted by an OP a full year later, or even more. SO is very time-dependent, the crowds mostly follow the freshest answers. -- about *this* problem, I still haven't found time to compare the performance with the accepted answer (after it's diagonalized properly of course, which is trivial)...

Comment: Appreciate the help. `[1..]` was purely an example, so your suggestion, while welcome, was not required. ~OP

Comment: @archaephyrryx there's more than just first sentence in my answer. :) I'll edit to clarify that it is a general solution, parallel to the code in accepted answer.

Comment: @WillNess I know, I was only referring to the first sentence in my answer. I have no problem whatsoever with anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I propose to build the pairs above the diagonal, that way a lot of duplicates are not even generated:

```
sums xs = zipWith (map . (+)) hs ts where
  (hs:ts) = tails xs
```

Now you have a list of lists, each containing sorted sums. Because they are sorted, it is possible to determine the next element of the sequence in a finite number of steps:

```
filtermerge :: (Ord a) => [[a]]->[a]
filtermerge ((h:t):ts) = h : filtermerge (insert t ts) where
  insert [] ts = ts
  insert xs [] = [xs]   
  insert h ([]:t) = insert h t
  insert (h:t) ts@((h1:t1):t2)
    | h < h1  = (h:t):ts
    | h == h1 = insert (h:t) $ insert t1 t2
    | otherwise = insert (h1:t1) $ insert (h:t) t2
filtermerge _ = []
```

Comment: your definition of "pairwise" might make more sense, but to correspond to the OP's code it should be `sums xs = zipWith (map . (+)) xs (tails xs)` (i.e. they include the diagonal as well).

Comment: also, it looks like `filtermerge` ~= `foldr (\(x:l) r-> x:union l r) []` (with the usual `union` definition, like in my answer too). I.e. [it's linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29#Linear_vs._tree-like_folds), so carries an `~ n/log n` penalty in complexity -- since the lists in question are all infinite, none of the `[]` handling cases will ever fire, so the "number of steps" in determining "the next element of the sequence" *is* finite, but is `O(i)`, with `i` the current index in the sequence.

Comment: @WillNess thanks, especially for the complexity analysis. I did consider that the lists in this question are infinite, but wrote a more general function to merge any sorted lists.

Comment: just by using `foldi` instead of `foldr` the complexity improves to log n from n. I use it all the time, as a general tool.

Comment: @WillNess Can you show how you get `log n`? (If it's explained in some references you mentioned, I didn't read them) The first pass of `pairs` gets you `n/2` applications of function. The second pass gets you `n/4`. Then `n/8`, etc. The infinite sum of these is `n`.

Comment: well, it's like a tree vs a list - the depth is log N vs N. the "function calls" that you refer to, are not one-of event: what is getting built, is a tree of `merge` "nodes" that will continue their work while their input isn't exhausted (i.e. for ever). So what counts, is how many levels to the top each produced number had to go through. I.e. depth. Hence the log factor. Tha't my thinking anyway. Evidence supports this - for primes, empirically the orders of grows for tree-folding code are the same as for the priority queue code by M.O'Neill. And that's only log above the optml, theoretcly

Comment: same for bottom-up mergesort - tree-folding (with [foldt instead of foldi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Tree-like_folds)) of `merge`s builds a finite almost-balanced tree of nodes. its complexity is well known. if that tree is degenerated into a list, it turns into an insertion sort or something. Of course it is important what kind of producers do we get - are they all roughly of same length (so tree shape stays the same) or not (so tree effectively degenerates with time). Here all the producers (the "`gens`") are infinite.

Comment: for primes, they are all infinite too, but produce at reducing frequency as we go to the right. So the skewed shape of foldi-built tree is a good fit. for some reason Dave Bayer (the originator of this stuff wrt the primes) went from the right-skewed "pairs" tree to balanced, "triples"-tree (I think he said it was faster). I myself never came around to test the times for the latter one because I thought the skewed shape is better (for the primes that is). In any case any tree will be better than a list.

Comment: @WillNess ugh, yes, I forgot the context was generation of infinite lists. Then recently when I said `foldi` had `log n` cost _in general_, I got strange looks. :)